# Is it safe to blend seeded grapes without removing seeds?

Tags: blender

It's doubtless unproductive and wearisome to [remove seeds from each seeded grape](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bez9THENCTw) before placing each into a blender. But if I don't remove seeds, can the seeds:

1. mangle or mar the blender blades?
2. chip or shatter the blender's container/jar?

[image]

Comment: I'd get seedless grapes if you can, seed usually do not taste good.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. You could blend pencils and pens with most modern blenders and there's no damage to the blender. Fruit seeds won't be a consideration except in use of the blended fruit. You might need to strain the output to remove bits of hull.

Answer (score 2):

The ‘real’ solution is seedless grapes.

Blending seeded grapes in itself isn’t any issue for the blender, it simply won’t care at all… however if you blend too long you will break through the seeds’ outer jelly layer & start to grate the seeds themselves, which will make the resulting purée bitter.

Comment: That's not much of a solution if you've got a grape vine. I got some rather nice muscat grapes on mine last year. Tasty if a little sharp, but full of pips.

Comment: Presumably, if you had a grapevine, you’d mention it in the question.

Comment: maybe. I would, but seeded grapes aren't common in supermarkets (in the bits of Europe I know at least, and I don't recall them in the US or Canada). So they seem likely to be coming from an atypical source. I only get a couple of bunches from mine, so it's not like it would be worth mentioning for quantity

Comment: Supermarkets in the UK predominantly sell seedless these days. Seeded are becoming a rarity.